# Rails Correlated Subquery Same table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord

My problem is converting the following SQL query to ActiveRecord Rails:

```
SELECT H1.* 
FROM USERS H1 
WHERE DAYS = (SELECT MAX(DAYS) FROM USERS H2
WHERE H1.COUNTRY = H2.COUNTRY
AND H1.NAME = H2.NAME
AND H1.MARKET = H2.MARKET
AND H1.TALL = H2.TALL)
```

My biggest issue here in converting this to Rails ActiveRecord is that the correlated subquery queries on the same table - "USERS" and aliasing the table names is illegal in ActiveRecord.

Find_by_sql is not an option for me either, since it cannot be used with other ActiveRecord functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write as

```
User.select("view.*")
    .from("User.group(:name, :country, :market, :tall)
    .maximum(:days), :view)")
    .where("days = ?", view.days)
```

Take a look at [`#from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) method to understand what's going on.

Comment: This didn't work for some reason. Can you explain why you are using count?

Comment: That still doesn't work. Might there be another syntax issue? I thought maybe "as max_days" should be part of the argument to the max function, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @jaamun What error you got tell me.. It will help me to fix. I am not able to run it, as I don't have *data*.

Comment: @jaamun try now.. It is fixed.. There was a *typo*.

Comment: I'll add that this works only for Rails 4. My website uses Rails 3 and thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.all(:select    => "users.COUNTRY, users.NAME, users.MARKET, users.TALL, users.DAYS",
         :joins     => "JOIN users AS H2 
                              ON H2.COUNTRY = users.COUNTRY AND 
                                 H2.NAME = users.NAME AND 
                                 H2.MARKET = users.MARKET AND 
                                 H2.TALL = users.TALL " ,
         :conditions => ["users.DAYS = H2.MAX(DAYS) "]
).each do |user|
  p "COUNTRY : #{user.COUNTRY}"
  p "NAME : #{user.NAME}"
  p "MARKET : #{user.MARKET}"
  p "TALL : #{user.TALL}"
  p "DAYS : #{user.DAYS}"
end
```

Comment: I should have clarified. Is there a way I can do this getting ActiveRecord objects? 'All' executes the query. I would like to just have the Active Record object such that I can call 'all' or 'each' on it later to execute the actual query.

Comment: It is a model name.. It should be `User`. Not `USERS`.

Comment: Right one, model name is USER not a USERS. Just i changed a model name.

Comment: in Rails tables names are `users` as per conventions :-) so `"USERS.COUNTRY, USERS.NAME,...` also needs to be changed.